# codeception in docker-compose - can't connect to Webdriver

Tags: php, nginx, docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver, codeception

I have somewhere an error in setting the Webdriver for my codeception and just can't figure it out.

when starting with

```
docker-compose run --rm codeception run
```

it finds the acceptance tests, and even reads the `$I->wantTo`

but then throws an error:

```
[ConnectionException] Can't connect to Webdriver at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub. Please make sure that Selenium Server or PhantomJS is running.
```

my `acceptance.suite.yml` is the following and I already tried replacing the url with chrome, nginx-web, the ip of the actual server (which does not make sense, but I really don't know what else to put in there)

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        # selenium webdriver
        - WebDriver:
            url: 'http://localhost/'
            browser: chrome

        - \Helper\Acceptance
```

my `docker-compose.yml`. I set the volumes in an additionl override

```
version: '2'
services:

  codeception:
    image: codeception/codeception:2.3.5
    depends_on:
      - nginx-web
      - php-web
      - chrome

  nginx-web:
    image:
      nginxext:0.5.6
    depends_on:
      - php-web
    expose:
      - 80

  php-web:
    image:
      phpext:0.7.0
    expose:
      - 9000

  # https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium
  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.7.1
    ports:
      - 4444
      - 5900
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found it. Given the various descriptions on the net using just url, I thought that I am setting the host also with the url. But you actually need to set the host and the url independently. So the solution is to add the service name of the selenium browser together with host.

```
        - WebDriver:
            url: http://localhost/      # url of app
            browser: chrome
            host: chrome                # selenium server host, default 127.0.0.1
#            port: 4444                 # selenium server port, default 4444
#            window_size: maximize      # or 640x480
```

Comment: Is that correct that `host` value is `chrome`? I thinks it should `localhost` instead.

Comment: Yes, it is correct for my environment. I am running it in a docker container and in the docker-compose.yml I call the service "chrome".

Comment: Aah, I see. (y)

Comment: I had to set url to http://chrome (or whatever the container name is) to make it work.